# How to filter from xml to get boot duration using powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, boot, event-log, get-winevent

so here is code and it gives a table as an output.

`$bootevents = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational"; id=100}
 $bootevent = [xml]$bootevents[0].ToXml()
 $bootevent.Event.EventData.Data`

If I want one entity record from **Name** like **BootTime** to be **filtered** and output instead of whole list/table being displayed,

what changes should be made?

Else could you advise any other way to get just **boot duration** using powershell?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just get the boottime:

```
$bootevent.Event.EventData.Data | ? name -eq boottime

Name     #text
----     -----
BootTime 30234
```

By the way, newer powershells (6, 7) can filter the named eventdata data fields.  And some filters can take wildcards.  But there's a 256 element limit on the logname.

```
Get-WinEvent @{logname='*Diagnostics-Performance*'; boottime=30234}


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
4/12/2020 1:11:05 PM           100 Warning          Windows has started up: …
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, shorter, option:

```
$bootevent.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Name='BootTime']")
```

Output:

```
Name     #text 
----     ----- 
BootTime 123355
```

Comment: yeah I was looking for this particular statement (.SelectSingleNode)..
..thanks a lot.. (╭ᵔ◡ᵔ)╭